# SharePoint Alternate Access Mapping error when indirectly using web services

Tags: sharepoint, alternate-access-mappings

**SharePoint web site** = http://myexample:3500

**SharePoint tester** (admin on domain, admin on SharePoint site collection) = IAmKyle

**Alternate Access Mapping**: I left it at the default which is http://myexample:3500 maps to itself, and the zone is "default".

My code was deployed as a farm solution and my .dll is in the GAC. I activated a feature on my site collection (url is above). What the code does is, when the user updates a SharePoint item, my code executes a LINQ query finding "related" items. Then the related items are updated. Here are the errors I get:

*On Windows Event Logs:*
Error loading and running event receiver [my receiver assembly]. Object reference not set to instance of an object.

*On SharePoint ULS event logs:*
Same error as I see in Windows Event logs. Also, I was getting errors about "alternate access mapping" not being configured for http://myexample:3500 but I'm not getting them anymore. Don't know why, I haven't changed anything.

*On IIS logs*
Getting some 401 responses for pages that I should be able to access. But, it only shows the tail end of the page in some cases e.g. "/mysite/mypage" so I'm unsure what the full URL is.

These errors are very confusing, my code 100% works on my test system. What network or sharepoint configurations should I be looking for? I'm assuming my code itself works fine considering that it does work on my test environment. Of course, I have more permissions on test since my username on test is the user who created the farm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get these errors when trying to activate the feature or when actually making a change to a list item?

Also, have you tried attaching the VS debugger to the process and having a look at what is going on?